# QMap doesn't insert when < operator compares two identical objects

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I'm trying to learn Qt. I experienced some issues but generally I find the solution by googling. But this afternoon I had an issue with QMap and I don't understand the problem.

I've created a class File and I overrided the `operator<` in order to be able to use it as key in `QMap<File, bool>`. The issue is that when I try to initialize a `QMap` by inserting entries the file map doesn't contain a duplicate entry in the sense of the implementation of the `operator<`.

```
 bool File::operator<(const File &file) const{
   if(comparator == NAME){
     if(this->getFileName() != file.getFileName()){
        return this->getFileName() < file.getFileName();
     }
     return false;
   }
   return this->getFileHash() < file.getFileHash();
}
```

`QMap` initialization:

```
for(File file: files){
    //filesCheckStatus edclared in the header file QMap<File, bool> filesCheckStatus;
    filesCheckStatus.insert(file, false);
}
```

In this example when comparator `NAME` is used entries with the same name (`QString`) are inserted only once.

In case I return false in all cases the final map contains only one entry (the first inserted).

Could someone explain this behavior?

Comment: It's how maps and sets work - a key can appear only once.

Comment: Try `QMultiMap`

Comment: File is the key not the file name which is a field of File and == is not used to ensure using unique keys (like equals in java).

Answer (score 0):

> In this example when comparator NAME is used entries with the same
>   name (QString) are inserted only once.

That's how maps and sets work. Each key is unique[1] in the collection. If you want multiple `File`s that compare the same, you could use `QMultiMap<File, bool>`, or `QVector<std::pair<File, bool>>`.

> In case I return false in all cases the final map contains only one
>   entry (the first inserted).

That's because the ordering that defines compares everything as equivalent to everything else.

1. Unique under the equivalence relation `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`. More generally for a binary predicate `comp`, you have a binary predicate `equiv` that is defined by `equiv(a, b) = !comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`